# thumb image from video url -react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

**Current behavior**

Videos list need to show thumbnail or poster but using video url as thumb image not working.

**Reproduction steps**

giving video url for poster to load thumb image

**Expected behavior**
:    for all list video need to have thumb image from video url

Comment: Ciao, can you show us the code you made unitl now? Thanks.

Comment: These are the steps doing:-

Step 1:-
Taking video using react-native-camera
Step 2:-
showing the recorded video using <Image source={{uri: video URL from API}} />
Step 3:-
onClick of image, opens react-native-video and video get played.



**Expected result**
1.  recording video is taking too much size(react-native-camera), need to reduce the 
     size of the recorded video.
2.  with video URL need to show thumbnail